# Content not confined to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel inside a Anchor Pane inside a JavaFX project. The problem I'm having is the content that's loaded inside the panel is not confined to the panel and cuts off text once it reaches the edge of the panel instead of moving on to the next line.

This is fine however if I test the panel inside a Jframe.

The Anchor panel was created and placed in the user interface using Scene Builder for JavaFX.
Below is the code where I make labels of ranging font sizes(this is to created a Word Cloud) and place them in a JPanel and then return this panel.

```
public JPanel nnsePairWordCloud() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
Database databaseConnection = new Database();
databaseConnection.getConnection();
ResultSet nnsePairs = databaseConnection.getNNSEPairInfoFromDatabase();
ResultSet nnseScores = databaseConnection.getNNSESimilarityResultsFromDatabase();

//adding words from the database to the array that will make up the word cloud
while(nnsePairs.next()) {
    String wordPair = nnsePairs.getString(1);
    WORDS.add(wordPair);
}

//adding each pairs weighting from the database - this will determine the size of the word
while(nnseScores.next()) {
    Double wordResult = nnseScores.getDouble(1);
    WEIGHTINGS.add(wordResult);
}
System.out.println("cloud data got");

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(380, 275);
    Cloud cloud = new Cloud();
   // cloud.setMinWeight(-1);
    //cloud.setMaxWeight(1);
    cloud.setMaxTagsToDisplay(300);
    //Random random = new Random();
    for (int i =0; i<WORDS.size(); i++) {
            cloud.addTag(new Tag(WORDS.get(i), WEIGHTINGS.get(i)));
    }
    for (Tag tag : cloud.tags()) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(tag.getName());
        label.setOpaque(false);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont((float) tag.getWeight() * 10));
        panel.add(label);
    }
    //frame.add(panel);
    //frame.setSize(800, 600);
    //frame.setVisible(true);
    return panel;

}
```

And here's the code where the panel is returned to and set - creates a SwingNode first and then loads the content. I had to do it this way so I could load the content in the JavaFX UI.

```
final SwingNode nodeForWordCloud = new SwingNode();
    createAndSetSwingContentForWordCloud(nodeForWordCloud);
    wordCloudBox.getChildren().add(nodeForWordCloud);

 private void createAndSetSwingContentForWordCloud(final SwingNode swingNode) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     swingNode.setContent(new WordCloud().initUI());
                 } catch (SQLException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(WordNetPairPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(WordNetPairPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(WordNetPairPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: Without more context and code, your question is equivalent to "guess what is wrong with code that I'm not showing you", and this us impossible to answer. Please improve your question. The [help] might help as well as [ask].

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels I've edited it and added code to try and help with what I'm asking. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

If I use a JavaFX FlowPane instead then it solves both the problems I was having. The content now flows within the pane and doesn't cut off and the content loads straight away as its no longer a swing component so it doesn't have to run on a separate thread.

Anyone having similar problems look up how the different layouts in Java FX work as this will help you figure out which one to use. These panels work very differently than they do in Swing.